# Как лишить пользователя возможности сделать заказ через строку браузера?

Tags: java, mvc, jsp, http, веб-программирование

Пользователь может сделать заказ минуя форму заказа, введя напрямую параметры заказа в строку браузера `blablabla?command=order&trainId=3` как избежать этого. Реализую MVC, использую jsp, фильтры, паттерн комманд.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Запомните одно простое правило: запросы, изменяющие какие-либо данные, должны *всегда* отправляться методом [POST](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#POST).

Comment: Это то да, но пользователю же никто не запретит вписать в строку браузера что он хочет, и отправить методом GET

Comment: Так проверяйте в контроллере, что бы метод POST был, в противном случае возвращайте `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: Спасибо, вкупе с последним комментом приму ответ как верный.

Answer (score 3):

Есть такой вариант: в форму пишете скрытое поле со случайным значением, его же сохраняете в сессии. При получении формы сверяете этот параметр с сохраненным в сессии. Если нет, или не совпали — Аларм!! )

При каждом выводе формы обновляете этот token в форме и в сессии. Помогает предотвратить CSRF-атаки, и ваш пример с заказом, как частный случай.

Comment: спасибо, а пользователь может используя строку браузера сохранить чтото в сессии?
И может лучше не в сессии а в requestScope?

Comment: и как сохранить случайное значение в сессию из jsp??